# How to unset a key in all objects in an array of objects?

Tags: php, unset

I'm trying to unset a key in all objects in an array of objects (basically removing any passwords), doing this:

```
    foreach ( $data['users'] as $user) {
        unset($user['password']);
    }
```

But it seems it doesn't effect the 'original' data ... how do I do this by reference (or whatever it takes to make this work as 'expected' – by which I mean, the key is removed from all objects in the original array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `$user` as reference like this :

```
// check this --------------v
foreach ( $data['users'] as &$user) {
    unset($user['password']);
}
```

Comment: Weird, I tried this initially but couldn't make it work. Now it 'somehow' does ... probably something else broke it at that time, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
foreach ( $data['users'] as $key => $user) {
    unset($data['users'][$key]['password']);
}
```

Or

```
foreach ( $data['users'] as &$user) {
    unset($user['password']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
array_walk($data['users'], function(&$a) {unset($a['password']);});
```

Comment: So, is there a performance gain compared to the other solutions, or? It seems from other peoples tests, that foreach is faster ...
One example here: http://www.ktorides.com/2015/02/php-array_walk-vs-foreach/
And there are others …

Comment: I don't know if ```foreach``` is faster or slower than ```array_walk```. Maybe with a small array the difference is negligible, so the problem doesn't exist. Usually, I like nonconformist solutions, in order to learn something more.